# Reload image from directory only when image changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, ftp

I have an FTP server which gets an image pushed to it from an Android application of mine when a picture is taken from the camera. The image being pushed to the FTP server has the same name each time (testImg.jpg), so for each image that is captured and sent to the FTP server, the image gets overwritten.

What I'd like to do, is... display the image from the FTP directory to a webpage each time it is a new image, i.e. each time testImg.jpg is overwritten, reload the page to show new testImg.jpg image.

I've done very minimal work with Javascript, and I'm not too sure how to go about doing this. I feel really stuck and clueless.

This is what I have so far in my live.html file (very minimal and doesn't do anything but show an image...):

```
<html>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
<body style="background-color:#eeeeee;">
    <div id="imgdiv">
        <img src="C:/inetpub/ftproot/testImg.jpg" id="img" onload="loadImg()" width="960" height="540">
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function loadImg() {
        alert('Image loaded');
    }
    //img = new Image();
    //img.src = "C:/inetpub/ftproot/testImg.jpg"

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: So how do you know image has changed ?

Comment: @MairajAhmad Each time I capture an image from my Android app, I am pushing that image out to the FTP server. So in that sense, I know the image -should- be changed... but I don't know how to recognise when the image has been changed in Javascript, and then to reload that image.

Comment: Are you using some server side language or is it a simple html page ?

Comment: @MairajAhmad Just a simple html page (I'll be running the page on the same server as the FTP, so can just access the files directly from the FTP directory).

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 1):

When you pushing image from Android, create one more file in the same folder of FTP - text file that will contain hash value for image.
Poll this file from javascript and when hash is changed then download new image.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Is it impossible to purely check if the image has been changed?

Comment: To check that image is changed, you have to download it - so you'll download image each time - I think it is not a good option.